# How to provide admin rights to user in OpenLDAP ? OpenLdap is installed on windows machine

Tags: openldap

How we can provide admin rights to user in OpenLdap(2.4.42) which is installed on Windows 7. For examle i have created a user:testuser in openldap and trying to give admin right to testuser.
I am using UserBooster Light for adding user, but solution from any tool or script will work for me.

*NOTE* manager is default user i think with admin rights,but it could not be used by our software which is using OpenLDAP users.

Comment: Unclear whether you mean admin rights within OpenLDAP itself or rights in terms of your application, but off topic either way.

Comment: Rights within OpenLDAP. In OpenLDAP terms it is:admin user in the OU